# XPath for Google Results: <em> and description without date

Tags: xpath

I have 3 questions:

1) How can I XPath the  text in the Google Results, the bold marked. If there's no , there should be nothing shown.

2) `=XPathOnUrl("https://www.google.de/search?q=KEYWORD&num=10");"//span[@class='st']")` This gives me the Google Description, but how can i get the description without the `<span class="f">` date?

3) I get the description with � as an "ä, ö, ü". How can these letters be displayed?

HTML DOM CODE:-

```
<span class="st">
<span class="f">18.11.2009 - </span>
This Thursday 19th November
<em>Moonshine</em>
turns 4 years old. I'm proud to say that's 4 years of Malaysian acts pretty much every month. We've ...
</span>
```

Comment: Can you show an HTML example?

Comment: [HERE](https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=moonshine+site:blogspot.com) you can see that every article has a date. How can I xpath just the full description?
  
  
  
`=XPathOnUrl("https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=moonshine+site:blogspot.com&num=10");"//span[@class='st']/text()[2]")` is working for me, but giving me just the 1st part of the text..

Answer (score 1):

The code I used for this issue

```
driver.get("https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl#q=moonshine+site:blogspot.com&nu%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bm=10");
              List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='f']/following-sibling::text()"));
              ele.toString();
             for(int i=0;i<ele.size();i++)
              {
                  System.out.println(ele.get(i).getText());
              }
```

This code throws an `InvalidSelectorException`

The result of the xpath expression `"//span[@class='f']/following-sibling::text()" is: [object Text].` It should be an element.

In future you try this following xpath to capture only the text i.e. description

```
//span[@class='f']/following-sibling::text()
```

***Actually you can't capture that text because this is selenium Open Issue***

[selenium-developer-activity] **`Issue 5459 in selenium:`** InvalidSelectorError: The result of the xpath expression is: [object Text]

you can find it in below link (issue details)
http://grokbase.com/t/gg/selenium-developer-activity/13475y4cgj/issue-5459-in-selenium-invalidselectorerror-the-result-of-the-xpath-expression-is-object-text

Answer (score 0):

Use below Xpath for same. It will return all the dates present on the page:-

```
//span[@class='f']/text()
```

if you just want text the use below xpath

```
//span[@class='st' and not(@class='f')]/text()
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: No, sorry, I want the description without any dates, if they exist.. Just the desciption.

Comment: thx, but still not working for me,. gives me the date aswell :/

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to get the German umlauts instead of �?

Comment: which language you are using. if you are using java then you can also use split method to extract only description from the xpath